# Why do we use $(this) inside a function acting on a jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, closures, this

From what I understand, `this` inside of a function refers to the object invoking the function. So, for instance, in

```
myObj = { name : "Charlie", getType : function() { return typeof(this); } }; 
console.log(myObj.getType());
```

the object invoking the function `getType` is `myObj` and therefore `typeof(this)` is `typeof(myObj)`.

Why, then, do I always see `$(this)` inside jQuery functions? For instance, in

```
$('.not-taller-than-50-pixels').each(function()
{
     if ($(this).height() > 50) $(this).height(50);
});
```

doesn't `$('.not-taller-than-50-pixels')` return an array of jQuery objects and so inside the `each` the invoking function is a jQuery object and so `this` would refer to that jQuery object and I can simply write `if (this.height() > 50) this.height(50);` ???

Comment: No, `this` will be the element currently being iterated over, which isn't a jQuery object, it's an element WITHIN a jQuery object. a single value in the "array-like" object. The same way where you get the value of an array when using `[1,2,3].forEach`, for example `1`, `2`, and `3`, rather than the value wrapped in another array such as `[1]`, `[2]` and `[3]`.

Comment: Kevin Bacon, so what type of element is it, exactly?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: In your example, it's a dom node, the same type of element you would get by using `document.getElementById('foo')`. Note however that $().each can be used on other types of collections such as native arrays or other array-like objects, so it may  not always be a dom node.

Comment: `.each()` is a method of jQuery, the passed function is not. Moreover, there are situations where `this` points to another object than the one from which the function is called. For example after doing `myObj.getType.bind(window)`, `this` permanently refers to the `window` object.

Comment: The function call  `$('.not-taller-than-50-pixels')` returns a single jQuery object which contains a collection of DOM nodes - it does not return an array of jQuery objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From what I understand, this inside of a function refers to the object invoking the function.

that is correct, if the function is being called as a property of that object. However, in your case, your jQuery collection isn't invoking the function as a property of the jQuery collection, instead it's invoking the function using either `.apply` or `.call` to set its context to the element currently being iterated over.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9.1/src/core.js#L628

It works similar to the way `Array.prototype.forEach` does. I assume that similarity is on purpose so that it seems familiar to most developers who are also familiar with native methods.

---

Here's an example more inline with your first snippet that WILL act the way you were expecting:

```js
$.fn.alertHeight = function () {
  alert(this.height());
}
$('body').alertHeight();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

Because the function is stored on the prototype of `$`, and invoked as a property of a jQuery collection (which is an instance of `$`,) `this` refers to the jQuery collection, thus allowing us to use `this.height()` directly to get the height of the first element in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

We use the `$(this)` because otherwise the `this` doesn't have a getter/setter method `.height()`. `$()` gives all selected elements access to jquery methods which plain javascript equivalents don't have. try `console.log($(this), " VS ", this);` remember that `$()` is a function.

Answer (score 1):

> doesn't $('.not-taller-than-50-pixels') return an array of jQuery
>   objects

No, `$('.not-taller-than-50-pixels')` does not return an array of JQuery objects. It returns a single JQuery object, which may wrap zero, one, or many DOM elements.

> and so inside the each the invoking function is a jQuery
>   object and so this would refer to that jQuery object and I can simply
>   write if (this.height() > 50) this.height(50); ???

The callback function passed to `.each()` is invoked for each of the DOM elements wrapped by the JQuery object, and when the callback function is invoked, the DOM element is used as the context. That is, inside the callback function `this` will reference the DOM element, not a JQuery object.

This is stated in the JQuery documentation for the [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function:

> When called it iterates over the DOM elements that are part of the
>   jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is passed the current
>   loop iteration, beginning from 0. More importantly, the callback is
>   fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword `this`
>   refers to the element.